Get all users from specific games on start.gg api
I was wondering if it is possible to get all users from Smash Ultimate using the start.gg API? I didn't see any documentation about getting all users, only tournaments or sets by a specific player.
Here is the api : https://developer.start.gg/docs/intro
Thanks in advance.
I already got all tournaments of Smash using this GraphQL query:
query TournamentsByVideogame($perPage: Int!, $videogameId: ID!) {
  tournaments(query: {
    perPage: $perPage
    page: 1
    filter: {
      past: true
        countryCode: "FR"
      videogameIds: [
        $videogameId
      ]
    }
  }) {
    pageInfo {
      totalPages
      page
    }
    nodes {
      createdAt,
      endAt,
      id
      name
      slug
    }
  }
}


If you managed to get all events from SSBU with your current code, it means you have the ids of these tournaments. From this page, you can fetch the entrants of given tournaments.
I hope I got it right. :)

Thanks I will try this ! I was wondering if there is another way than fetching every ssbu's tournaments and just get all users from user table
